# (PHP) Replace string of array elements using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => "http://example1.com"
    [1] => "http://example2.com"
    [2] => "http://example3.com"
    ...
)
```

And I want to replace the `http` with `https` of each elements using RegEx. I tried:

```
$Regex = "/http/";
$str_rpl = '${1}s';
...
foreach ($url_array as $key => $value) {
  $value = preg_replace($Regex, $str_rpl, $value);
}
print_r($url_array);
```

But the result array is still the same. Any thought?

Comment: You actually print an array without change it. Also you can use `str_replace` instead Regex :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This expression might also work:

```
^http\K(?=:)
```

which we can add more boundaries, and for instance validate the URLs, if necessary, such as:

```
^http\K(?=:\/\/[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zHDnXB/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/^http\K(?=:\/\/[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]+)/si';
$str = '  http://example1.com  ';
$subst = 's';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, trim($str));
```

#### Output

```
https://example1.com
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2j0k8M/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/2j0k8M/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You actually print an array without changing it. Why do you need regex for this?

*Edited with Casimir et Hippolyte's hint:*

**This is a solution using regex:**

```
$url_array = array
(
    0 => "http://example1.com",
    1 => "http://example2.com",
    2 => "http://example3.com",

);

$url_array = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $url_array);
print_r($url_array);
```

[PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0979ab95da264b219d1c02394ab8d67c8b728a18)

**Without regex:**

```
$url_array = array
(
    0 => "http://example1.com",
    1 => "http://example2.com",
    2 => "http://example3.com",

);

$url_array = str_replace("http://", "https://", $url_array);
print_r($url_array);
```

[PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6110112a460e1a34c9d983941f3a3f026d96b8c3)

Comment: Using `foreach` loops is useless, [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can take an array as subject parameter and return an array.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are not modifying the array values at all. In your example, you are operating on the copies of array values. To actually modify array elements:

1. use reference mark

```php
foreach($foo as $key => &$value) {
   $value = 'new value';
}
```

2. or use for instead of foreach loop

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($foo); $i++) {
   $foo[$i] = 'new value';
}
```

Going back to your question, you can also solve your problem without using regex (whenever you can, it is always better to not use regex [less problems, simpler debugging, testing etc.])

```php
$tmp = array_map(static function(string $value) {
    return str_replace('http://', 'https://', $value);
}, $url_array);

print_r($tmp);
```

**EDIT**:

As Casimir pointed out, since str_replace can take array as third argument, you can just do:

```php
$tmp = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url_array);
```

Comment: `$tmp = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url_array);` does the same thing, without using `array_map`. (see my comment for andreah's answer).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for pointing it out. Edited the answer.